# How to check which feild in mongodb is updated and store that in another feild

Tags: mongodb

suppose there is a db - Profiles , inside that a collection - Managers ,
now in this collection if in one document a field is updated like "current location" which was set to "Mumbai" is changed to "Bangalore".

Then how to catch that which field is updated (here its "current location") and store that name of field in the same document in another field.

Comment: where is your database hosted?

Comment: its on cloud.........but I want to test on my local server